# How can I manage active nav tabs in react bootstrap with multiple URLs highlighting the same tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap Navbar to handle the navigation of my site.
This is the simple Navbar I have.

```js
const AppNavbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="theme-navbar">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">My Projects</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav activeKey={location.pathname} className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="/projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/work">Ongoing Tasks</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

I use `activeKey={location.pathname}` to highlight the active `Nav.Link`.
However, I'd like that when the URL is '/' the `<Nav.Link href="/projects">Projects</Nav.Link>` were highlighted too since I'm rendering the same view in both cases.

Here is the Routes excerpt to make this clearer.

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<ProjectList />} />
    <Route path="/projects" element={<ProjectList />} />
    <Route path="/work" element={<InprogressTaskList />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Does react-bootstrap support this?

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this question I came up with the answer, so I write it down just in case someone can use it.

The solution is basically control the activeKey value as follows:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppNavbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const activeKey = location.pathname === '/' ? '/projects' : location.pathname;

  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="theme-navbar">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/">My Projects</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav activeKey={activeKey} className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="/projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/work">Ongoing Tasks</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

Also, note that in order to make Nav.Link to work properly with react-router (this is, they change the URL without hitting the server, and still highlight the active tab) you need to use the following:

```js
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppNavbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const activeKey = location.pathname === '/' ? '/projects' : location.pathname;

  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="theme-navbar">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">
          Paint Projects
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav activeKey={activeKey} className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={Link} eventKey="/projects" to="/projects">
              Projects
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} eventKey="/work" to="/work">
              Ongoing Tasks
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```